# SQL relation 1 key not 2 keys between tables

Tags: sql

I want to define a foreign key constraint between the table `Speler` and the table `Wedstrijd`. I want the key on the `Wedstrijd` table, but when I use this code in my SQL console:

```
ALTER TABLE Speler
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idSpeler) REFERENCES Wedstrijd(idWedstrijd);
```

It puts a key on the table `Speler` and on the table `Wedstrijd`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Some table layouts and perhaps sample data would really be helpful.  And what does it mean that it "puts a key on [both] tables"?

Comment: If you run the code above, how can it put it on `Wedstrijd` table???

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Wedstrijd
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idWedstrijd) REFERENCES Speler(idSpeler);
```

Comment: Still gives a key in both tables

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "solving" what you perceive as your problem, I think you have a different problem:

By mapping `idSpeler` to `idWedstrijd`, you are basically saying that a Speler (*Player*) **is equal to** a Wedstrijd (*Match*). That becomes a 1:1 relation which is then shown as a line with two yellow 'key'-endings (assuming you are using SQL Server).

It is very likely to me that instead you need to create a linking table **`WedstrijdSpeler`** that sits between the other two tables.

Then the new table **`WedstrijdSpeler`** needs to be given 2 Foreign Keys:

- `WedstrijdSpeler.idWedstrijd -> Wedstrijd.idWedstrijd`
- `WedstrijdSpeler.idSpeler -> Speler.idSpeler`.

Then you can give **`WedstrijdSpeler`** either a combined Primary Key (containing both fields `idWedstrijd` and `idSpeler`), or you can add a third field `idWedstrijdSpeler` and make that the Primary Key. Either approach will do, it is up to you.